# Widget on High Sierra with APFS

Tags: widget, monit, apfs

Although still beta (beta 4 at time of writing) in my testing any version of MacOS using APFS will not display any Disk information within Monit Widget. The summary bar shows "Disk 0%" and once selected the sub-content is not displayed/not even expanded. All other categories in Monit Widget appear to work as expected.

Is anybody else seeing the same?

[image: Monit Widget with APFS]

Answer (score 0):

Yes same here !
Apparently the version 1.2.1 resolves this problem by adding APFS compatibility